# Using the same DE, but contacts entered Journeys were different

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have used the same Data extension for 2 journeys and have not used any filters. However, the contacts that enter the journeys weren't the same.

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you used the same filters in both journeys? Please provide more details about your setup and issue, as it's hard to troubleshoot with the amount of information currently provided.

Comment: Hi, there weren't any filters in both Journeys. I've updated my question with images.

Comment: As told by saleforceSupport once, the figures under the activities doesnt allways correspond with the reality. Can you check the numbers are right?

Answer (score 1):

So, nothing was wrong in this case.

I've checked all the data belonging to the journey themselves and found out that these two journeys have been using the same DE, which was the destination DE of an ongoing Automation.

With dynamic DE, contacts entered can be added, modified, or deleted. This was the main cause for the issue, causing a change in number of contacts entered the journeys.